# Full-text search mysql with ngram don't search with punctuations

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have some problem in searching in MySql with full-text search.
I created an table with name:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id`               VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `title`            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `content`          TEXT         NOT NULL,
  `view_count`       BIGINT       NOT NULL,
  `status`           TINYINT      NOT NULL             DEFAULT 1,
  `created_at`       DATETIME     NOT NULL,
  `updated_at`       DATETIME
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX `ft_articles` ON `articles` (`title`, `content`) WITH PARSER ngram;
```

I searched with statement and search result with 0 rows found. I don't know why, although `へ…太らず` exist in title, but when search with `太らず` I saw one record. The same to `う！魅力`, `いい？人に`. It seems that mysql don't search punctuations in Japanese.

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title, content)
    AGAINST ('"へ…太らず"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search-mecab.html) you need to install the MeCab parser to do full text search in Japanese.  The ngram parser appears to not be working.

Comment: But I also find ngram support for Japanese. But I can't search exact a phrase with punctuations in phrase. For example: I can search with `？人に`, but I don't with `いい？人に`